# How to iterate over items returned by an Android JavascriptInterface?

Tags: java, javascript, android, performance

I have the following Java interfaces,

```
public interface JavascriptInterface
{
    public MyIterator getItems();
}

public interface MyIterator
{
    public boolean hasNext();
    public String next();
}
```

which I expose as an API to a JavaScript web application:

```
Webview webview;
JavascriptInterface webapi;

//init webview and webapi [..]

webview.addJavascriptInterface(webapi, "webapi");
```

I wonder if there is a possibility to iterate over the items with a JavaScript for-loop like this:

```
for (var item in webapi.getItems())
{
    //do something with item [..]
}
```

What type/methods do I have to use/implement instead of `MyIterator` to make this possible, or can I convert it somehow (with a JavaScript helper)?
I currently return a `String` object with JSON and parse it with a JavaScript library. Is there an easier/faster solution?

Edit: The JSON solution also has the issue, that I can only provide a copy of static data and can not invoke methods.

Comment: You can only pass primitives and strings back from your javascript interface, but that still leaves you with a lot of options. In the simplest case you could return "{'item one','item two'}" and your javascript would treat it as an array, but you could also return a much more complex JSON object. In any case your method signature will need to return a string.

I hope that's helpful.

Comment: At least I can also return any other custom interface and invoke methods on it. So I'm not quite sure if I should abandon the idea so fast. A simple foreach implementation only needs a `boolean hasNext()` and a `AnySupportedType next()` method. But how can this be done in javascript? :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Android would fully support [JavaScript version 1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/new_in_javascript_1.7), I could to something like this, to map between Java and JavaScript Iterable (unfortunately they does not support it yet, but maybe this will work in the future):

```
function MyIterable(iterable)
{
    this.iterable = iterable;
}

MyIterable.prototype.__iterator__ = function() {
    return new MyIterator(this.iterable.iterator());
};

function MyIterator(iterator) {
    this.iterator = iterator;
}

MyIterator.prototype.next = function() {
    if (this.iterator.hasNext())
        return this.iterator.next();
    else
        throw StopIteration;
};

for (var item in new MyIterable(webapi.getItems()))
{
    //do something with item [..]
}
```

or

```
function createIterator(iterable)
{
    var iterator = iterable.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext())
        yield iterator.next();
    throw StopIteration;
}

for (var item in createIterator(webapi.getItems()))
{
    //do something with item [..]
}
```

Note: This time I assume `webapi.getItems()` returns a Java `Iterable<T>`.

I dont know if `__iterator__()` is a valid method name in Java, but you could also think about returning a custom Iterable/Iterator interface in Java, implementing `__iterator__()`, and `next()`. The only question is, how to throw the `StopIteration` exception.

Answer (score 0):

To give you an idea, I could do something like this:

```
function toArray(iterator)
{
    arr = new Array();
    while (iterator.hasNext())
         arr.push(iterator.next());
    return arr;
}

for (var item in toArray(webapi.getItems()))
{
    //do something with item [..]
}
```

But I am still not totally happy with this, because it iterates when I call `toArray()`, and I cant `break;`.
So its a little bit cheated..